# jQuery change date from format to another one

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an input text with id `CldrFrom`

It has date like this: `04/17/2014` **in other words** mm/dd/yyyy

I want to change it to this format `17-04-2014` **in other words** dd-mm-yyyy

I want to do that in jQuery.

#### What I have tried

```
var currentDate = $(#CldrFrom").val();
val = val.replace("/", "-");
```

So I replaced the `/` with `-` but I still need to make the day as the first not the month.
how please?

#### Edit

to take the date I am using a datepicker library.
I call it like this:

```
$("#CldrFrom, #CldrTo").datepicker();
```

is there anyway so directly I make that library prints dates in this format `dd-mm-yyyy` ?

Comment: if you use jQuery UI, you can do it with $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-MM-yyyy', new Date())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split and join it together in the order you want

```
var currentDate = $("#CldrFrom").val();
var dateArr     = currentDate.split('/');
var val         = dateArr[1] + '-' + dateArr[0]  + '-' + dateArr[2];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7PP9h/)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a simple regex to `.replace()` method:

```
var currentDate = $("#CldrFrom").val(),
    val         = currentDate.replace(/\//g , "-");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N6RKM/)**