# How to convert datetime YYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss to MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss AM/PM

Tags: jquery

Can any one help me to covert the datetime to this

```
04/01/2017 12:30:05 PM
```

format using jquery.

Comment: did you try string manipulation?

Comment: No i didn't try

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23080023/4248328   OR  https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1009120/Convert-one-Date-format-into-another-date-format-i

Comment: Made headline generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use only jQuery, Try this:

```js
/* Convert your date string to date object */

var strDate = "2017-04-01 12:30:05"
var regex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
var arrDate = regex.exec(strDate); 
var objDate = new Date(
    (+arrDate[1]),
    (+arrDate[2])-1, // Month starts at 0!
    (+arrDate[3]),
    (+arrDate[4]),
    (+arrDate[5]),
    (+arrDate[6])
);

/* Convert the date object to string with format of your choice */

var newDate = objDate.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + objDate.getDate() + '/' + objDate.getFullYear();

/* Get the time in your format */

var newTime = objDate.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric',minute:'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: true });

/* Concatenate new date and new time */

alert(newDate + " " + newTime);
```

Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7712335/5619896) to convert your date string to date object.

Comment: thanq so much @Senjuti Mahapatra.

Comment: when give this date(2017-04-11 02:15:06),it is giving AM.

Comment: @user123 Yes because the time here is given in 24 HR format. So, 02:00 is 2 AM in the night, while 14:00 is 2 PM in the noon.

Comment: How can we change that to 12 HR format.Can you tell.

Comment: Thanq so much @Senjuti Mahapatra

Comment: How can i change to 24 HRS Format,have to  remove hour12: true  ??? @Senjuti Mahapatra

Comment: @user123 Set `hour12: false`

Comment: Ya i did that hour12: false but AM/PM is not coming..how to set AM/PM

Comment: @user123 There is no AM/PM if you choose 24 hr format (`hour12: false`). AM/PM is only for 12 hr format (`hour12: true`).

Comment: I need to put AM/PM in my project any alternate way.

Comment: Check if hour is greater than 12 and <=24, append PM else AM.

Comment: Thanq so much @ Senjuti Mahapatra

Answer (score 0):

Using `getDate` , `getMonth` , `getFullYear` and for time use `getHours` , `getMinutes` and `getSeconds` you can do this easily and get format what ever you want.

```js
var formattedDate =new Date("04/01/2017 12:30:05 PM");
var d = formattedDate.getDate();
var m =  formattedDate.getMonth();
m += 1;  // months are 0-11
var y = formattedDate.getFullYear();
var t = formattedDate.getHours() + ":" + formattedDate.getMinutes() + ":" + formattedDate.getSeconds();
console.log(d + "_" + m + "_" + y);
console.log(m + "_" + d + "_" + y);
console.log ('Time: ' + t );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```